# How to change HTML select name based on option value

Tags: javascript

How can I get option value. I want to change the `name="<value>"` based on selected option value.
So that I can send name value to the spring controller along with `onChange=""`.

I want to change `select name="report/leavereport/weeklysummery"` based on option selected value.

```
 <select  name="" onChange="document.getReportAll.submit()">
        <option  value="">Select Report Type</option>
        <option  value="report">TIME REPORT</option>
        <option  value="leavereport">LEAVE REPORT</option>
        <option  value="weeklysummery">TIME SUMMARY</option>
 </select>
```

Thank you,

Comment: document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].name=document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value

Comment: That seems a very odd requirement. Usually, field *names* are consistent between form submissions, and field *values* vary.

Comment: Are you going to run into problems if someone visits without JavaScript enabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shortest change, given that code and modern browsers, would be:

```
onChange="this.name = this.value; document.getReportAll.submit()"
```

...since within the attribute event handler, `this` refers to the select element and modern browsers reflect the option value as `value` in single-selects.

Answer (score 0):

Set a id to the `select`.

```
<select id="select"...>...</select>
```

---

Then set the `onchange` event of the `select` element. It fires when a option is selected.

If the selector `value` is undefined, then the browser doesn't support it, so it's possible to get the selected element iterating the options and checking if the attribute `selected` is included. I'd not use `querySelector` because older browsers may not support it.

```
var selector = document.getElementById('select');

selector.onchange = function() {

    var value = this.value;

    if(!value) {

        for(var i = 0, op; op = selector.children[i]; i ++) {
            // Check if the attribute selected is valid
            if(op.getAttribute('selected')) {
                value = op.value;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    this.name = value;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible (unobtrusive) solution using `getAttribute` and `setAttribute`.

The script listens for a click on any of the `options` and then updates the value of the `name` attribute of `select`, based on the value of the `value` attribute of the `option`.

```js
var options = document.getElementsByTagName('option');

function changeName() {
var value = this.getAttribute('value');
window.alert('name = "' + value + '"');
this.parentNode.setAttribute('name',value);
}

for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
options[i].addEventListener('click',changeName,false);
}
```

```html
<select  name="">
<option  value="">Select Report Type</option>
<option  value="report">TIME REPORT</option>
<option  value="leavereport">LEAVE REPORT</option>
<option  value="weeklysummary">TIME SUMMARY</option>
</select>
```